# building apr-util 64 bit Mac OS X builds 32-bit version

Tags: makefile, x86-64, configure, apr

I am currently building a 32/64 bit version of apr by configuring and building twice and combining the output with lipo, (apr-1.4.5)
I am trying to accomplish the same thing with the 64-bit version with apr-util-1.4.1, but all of my output seems to be i386 32bit,
I am trying to configure and build with the following line:

```
./configure --target=x86_64 --prefix=`pwd`/64bit  --with-apr=`pwd`/../apr-1.4.5 CFLAGS="-m64" && make all && make install
```

I have also tried the following:

```
./configure --build=x86_64 --prefix=`pwd`/64bit  --with-apr=`pwd`/../apr-1.4.5 && make all && make install

./configure --build=x86_64 --prefix=`pwd`/64bit  --with-apr=`pwd`/../apr-1.4.5 CFLAGS="-m64" && make all && make install
```

and various other variants, presumably somebody is building a x86_64 version.

to clarify I am looking at the static library, the .a file, not the dynamic library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rules.mk file there is a CFLAG that is getting set to -m32 which forces 32 bit, this is added by the ./configure script and must be removed after configure...